# PyQt5 set multiple MIME Types in Clipboard

Tags: python, pyqt5, mime, qclipboard

I have been trying to create an HTML-Like table using PyQt5 in terms of copying functionality.

However, I am stuck at the following issue: when copying data from an HTML table and pasting to https://madebyevan.com/clipboard-test/, I get the following:

[image: HTML table MIMES]

There are two types of data listed, `text/plain` and `text/html`, which is my goal.

However, in PyQt5's QClipboard, I can only find QClipboard.setMimeData which uses a single QMimeData.

I was not able to define 2 MIME types in a single QMimeData object or use 2 different QMimeData objects in QClipboard.setMimeData.

Is there a way to have 2 MIME types in clipboard using QClipboard?

Why am I trying to do this?
I would like the same copied data to be paste-able in E-Mail software as a `text/html` table type but in Notepad as `text/plain` as `text/html` does not work there.

Useful links:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html

Comment: "I was not able to define 2 MIME types in a single QMimeData object": then please [edit] your question and show a [mre] of your attempt. Besides, if you want to set HTML *and* text, you should just use [`mime.setHtml()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#setHtml) and [`mime.setText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedata.html#setText).

Comment: Perfect! that was just what I needed, I thought you could store only 1 MIME type, thank you.